# Magento 2: Composer install for my own module

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I'm have my own magento 2 module. It's allready uploaded on Gitlab. 
What i must do to install this module using `composer require`?

Comment: @Krishati95Dev yes, but i have an error:
The "https://github.com/arefyevi/test/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Comment: @Krishati95Dev i've created test emty module and uploaded them on github, but my module on GitLab.

Comment: @Krishati95Dev https://github.com/arefyevi/test

Answer (score 2):

To be able to install the module using composer, Your module should be available at [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/), You can link your git repository there. So, you need to Register, and Submit your package there first.

Comment: Thanks for information. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your test module, you just need to move the repository block from your package's `composer.json` to the main composer file in your Magento installation.

First, fix your module composer file by removing the repository block.

`<module-directory>/composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "illia/module-test",
    "description": "13132",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mage2Gen",
            "email": "info@mage2gen.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Illia\\Test\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Commit those changes, then add a reference to your repository in

`<magento-installation-dir>/composer.json`

```
"repositories": [
        {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
     },
     {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/arefyevi/test.git"
    }
],
```

Finally, require your package and install

> composer require illia/module-test @dev

This process is the same regardless if you're using **Gitlab** or **Github**, you'll just need to update the repository url to point to the correct package.